# Mysql avoid duplicate URLS

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an SQL statement to check if a field exists?
Example: 
I have a database with the following: `URL, IsCrawled, Level` Etc.
I need to check to see if the URL is already there.
I do not care about the other fields.
I am writing a very fast crawler, and this is needed.

Comment: You could put a unique index on the URL field so that the same URL cannot be inserted twice.

Comment: Tackle this from the DB side. Add a unique index for the url field. It will enforce the unique constraint and improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a plain select under any index:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE URL = @URL
```

If the select isn't null then there's already one.

Now, another better idea depending on your problem would be to add a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) so by design your DB will not allow duplicates of that value.

Now, going a little forward if you want to compare only part of the URL to see (ie the domain) then you can use the [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) comparison function to see if there's already one URL stored with the same domain name.

Comment: This wouldn't take into account extraneous parameters, such as those for marketing campaigns et cetera, which would screw up the checking process.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `urls` (`URL`)
```

or simple,

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD UNIQUE(`URL`);
```

Though, I use the first method. Have only read about the second method to work too. *It may not be so*.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableName
WHERE `URL` = 'urlHERE'
```

It will have a result of `0` if it doesn't exists. Or add a unique index on the fieldd `URL`

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD CONSTRAINT indexName UNIQUE (`Url`)
```

in this way, the `Insert` statement will fail if you insert a url which already exists.